# Implementing SSO + OAuth with google

Tags: python, django, google-apps, google-openid, google-sso

All i wanted to do is to implement Single Sign On, for users with google apps on custom domain. Eg. startup.com has configured their domain, by purchasing google apps for business for their domain. They have gmail address configured at users@startup.com.

I have a django app.
Now in case i want to implement SSO for custom google apps domain, i have couple of options:

1. Hybrid Open ID + OAuth + SSO
2. Custom OAuth + SSO.

The documentation for 1. is quite ample and they have shown it. 
How about going 2nd way, since i just wanted to log the users with their email ids. I could do it with OAuth as well. How good is it to implement SSO + OAuth together? 
Are there any good libraries that help me doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes care of what you are looking for: https://github.com/simul14/django-googleappsauth

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) it allows you to use both OpenID and OAuth with Google which should help with you issue.

Comment: i am more concerned with, SSO.